# Find $m$ such that the line is normal to the given hyperbola

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

> Find $m$ such that $y=mx+\frac{25}{\sqrt3}$ is normal to $$\frac{x^2} {16}-\frac{y^2}9=1$$

How to go about this question. I don't find any clue.

Comment: Start by finding the slope of the tangent to the curve at any point. Hint: Implicit differentiation.

Comment: @EuxhenH I get $dy/dx=9x/16y$. Now?

Comment: https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-coordinate-geometry/tangent-and-normal.aspx#how-do-you-find-the-equation-of-the-normal-to-an-ellipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say it is normal at point $T(a,b)\in\mathcal{H}$, then from the derivative we get $$ {a\over 8} - {2bk\over 9}=0$$ where $$k = y'(a) = -{1\over m}$$

So we have $$k={9a\over 16b}\implies m = -{16b\over 9a}$$

Since $T$ is on this normal we have $$b =  -{16b\over 9a} \cdot a +{25\over \sqrt{3}}\implies b= 3\sqrt{3}$$

Plugin in $${a^2\over 16}-{27\over 9} =1\implies a=\pm 8$$

So $\boxed{m= \pm {2\sqrt{3}\over 3}}$